# How to get events handlers for custom controls in Generic.Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to create a custom control with two buttons (for an example). I have a Generic.Xaml file which looks like this

```
<Style TargetType="local:DoubleButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:DoubleButton">
                <Grid>                    

                    <Button x:Name="leftButton" Click="leftButtonClick" />

                    <Button x:Name="rightButton" />

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and the DoubleButton class looks like this:

```
public sealed class DoubleButton : Control
{
    public DoubleButton()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(DoubleButton);
    }

    public void leftButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog("message");
    }
}
```

But this method never gets called. If anybody has an idea on how raise events for custom controls that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: I do this via the PART at apply template time.  I really don't know if it's the *approved* way or not, but it's something for you to check out if you're having a problem.

Comment: @GayotFow Thanks for the information. Whether it be the approved way or not, it works. I have credited you in the question.

Comment: Well done!  I can add an answer that includes the attribute definition and the right declaration for the PART if that's of any use.  I suppose I can add it to the community wiki also.

Comment: @GrayotFow I couldn't find much on Google to do with PART and what it does so I made a solution without it. However if it's something important then I'm sure me, and the next person who comes across the problem would be greatful.

Comment: I don't want to be a party pooper but you should use an ICommand on your ViewModel. In that case whatever VM you will assign to the Control it would execute the command specific to a VM. That is if you are using MvvM. HTH. And there won't be any need for `Override` anywhere in your code.

Comment: @XAMlMAX, totally agree, but that's exposing a dependency property on the control.  Different question :) :)

Comment: @GayotFow you are right but this info was like your answer for people who will read this article after :-), I actually added this question to favourites, you never know when it might come in handy and BTW well done!.

Comment: @XAMlMAX, I'm going to add this to the community wiki, we can see how many views it gets later :)

Comment: I noticed you tagged your question as both WPF and Windows 8/Metro. Since you don't mention the design language anywhere in here I gather you meant the old moniker of Windows Store Apps, so I retagged your question as WinRT/XAML and Windows Runtime since these are the underlying technology tags. If you were looking for generic answers applicable to both "Store Apps" and "WPF" - feel free to retag again.

Comment: Your solution would have worked: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/01/walkthrough-custom-control-in-xaml-isnt.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a given control is to have an event handler, you can set it up like this...

```
            <Grid>
                <Button x:Name="PART_leftButton"  />
                <Button x:Name="PART_rightButton" />
            </Grid>
```

where the first part of the name begins with PART_

The code-behind for the control looks like this...

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_leftButton", Type = typeof(Button))]
public class CustomControl1 : Control
{
    static CustomControl1()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1)));
    }
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        var button = Template.FindName("PART_leftButton", this) as Button;
        if (button != null)
        {
            button.Click += (s, a) => Console.WriteLine(@"click");
        }
    }
}
```

... the event handler is added when the control template is applied.  Note the attribute in the class definition, the "`TemplatePartAttribute`".

Leaving this attribute out will not make your program crash or do anything differently.  It's there as a professional courtesy to those who might read your code later.  AND it is used by `Blend` and other surface designers.  It's a very helpful convention.

Comment: I'm wondering, @Gayot, is there some specific reason for calling `DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata()` instead of plainly setting `this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(...)`?

Comment: Very much!  You need to pick up inherited properties.  To check, use a theme file with and without that override.

Comment: Well, I've been just setting `DefaultStyleKey` for years since that's what you get in the templated/custom control VS item template and haven't noticed a problem, so if you could elaborate a bit on what you mean by "picking up inherited properties" - I really want to learn!

Comment: Then it's likely that I have misunderstood your question.  I suggest reading this  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.defaultstylekey(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now - thanks, that article is a bit enlightening. Also I get it now that you were answering the question as a WPF one while I was thinking WinRT/XAML since OP mentioned Windows-8/Microsoft-Metro tags and in WinRT/XAML you don't get the `OverrideMetadata()` method and rather simply set the property.

Comment: @FilipSkakun, if you write about this finding in your blog, please ping me.  I'd like to read it.